# I'm trying to install pip install -U pydantic on Windows and it keeps getting denied

Tags: python, windows, pip, pydantic, access-denied

Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\Users\anany\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\~ydantic_core\_pydantic_core.cp311-win_amd64.pyd'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

I want to generate reports but it keeps getting denied access.

Comment: Try to use powershell or cmd with Administrator mode.

Answer (score 2):

I've run into this issue when using a package in an ipynb in VScode. I think it's "file in use" permission issues. Closing VScode and re-running the command has worked for me.

Comment: I tried it didnt work for me

Comment: @AnanyaMishra, try closing all code editors (restart can't hurt as well). Then run "pip uninstall pydantic". Then run "pip install pydantic". If that fails, then it could be user issues, like parker said

Answer (score 1):

2 Ideas to help fix your problem

1. Run the command line as admin, right-click the program or command prompt and select "Run as Administrator".

If that doesn't work try this

2. Open another command prompt as administrator, and enter the following code

`pip install --user package_name`

> Replace "package_name" with the package you are looking to install

Comment: raise PydanticImportError(
pydantic.errors.PydanticImportError: `BaseSettings` has been moved to the `pydantic-settings` package. See https://docs.pydantic.dev/2.0.2/migration/#basesettings-has-moved-to-pydantic-settings for more details.
i tried installing package but it still gave me  the same error